# Pass an object from one controller action to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, mongoid, stripe-payments

I have a `request` object that I want to pass to my `charges_controller`. I can pass it in to the `new` action but after that new action is called I need that same `request` object passed to the create object in the same `charges_controller`. I can not get it. Here is the initial `request_controller` action passing the `request_id` to the charges controller.

`````
class Users::RequestsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!

def create
  @user = current_user
    if @request = @user.request.create!(authorization_params)
      if @request.user_paying == true
        redirect_to new_users_charge_path(id: @request)
      else
        redirect_to users_dashboard_path
      end
    else
      redirect_to users_dashboard_path, :error => "There is something wrong and your request has not been submitted."
    end
end````
`````

It then passes it to the new method in the charges controller. Here is my charges controller.

```
class Managers::ChargesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @request = Request.find(params[:id])
    @user = current_user
    @amount = @request.user_amount
  end

  def create
    # Amount in cents
    @request = Request.find params[:request_id]
    @user = current_user
    @amount = @request.user_amount

customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
  :email => @user.email,
  :card  => params[:stripeToken]
)

charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
  :customer    => customer.id,
  :amount      => @amount,
  :description => 'Manager Paid Report',
  :currency    => 'usd'
)
@request.report_paid = true
@request.save!
redirect_to managers_dashboard_path, :notice => "You have succesfully requested a pre-paid report from #{@reportapproval.tenant_last_name}."

rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to managers_charges_path
end
end
```

I can get the request info into the `charges/new.html` view. But when I create the charge the request is not found. How can I pass the request to the create action?

Here is the new view...

```
<h4>Total Payment Due: <%= number_to_currency(@amount.to_i/100.0) %>
  <%= form_tag users_charges_path do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :request_id, @request.id %>
<br />
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"   class="stripe-button"
        data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
        data-description="Payment"
        data-amount="<%= @amount %>"
        data-locale="auto" >
        </script>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Controllers should not communicate between themselves directly. They should be DRY and short. Have you considered porting this business logic on a service, or common layer underneath the controllers?

Comment: I don't think that you need to pass the request around: i think that you just need to pass some small amount of data around, eg the id of the request object.  This could most cleanly be passed in a param.

Comment: @matheus208 i am fairly new i have heard about services, i will read up on them. I assume they are different than an actual model.

Comment: @max actually i just need the charge to be able to get info from the request and post to the request. In my controller it isvtrying to find the request by id but I am not sure how to have new pass create the ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controllers simply respond to HTTP requests - there is no way to forward a request internally in Rails. This is a very conscious design decision.

If you need to stash data in between requests you would either save it in the database, the session or some sort of caching mechanism like Memcached/Redis.

Most commonly in Rails you stash data in the database and pass ID's or other unique identifiers in the request parameters.

If you need to pass the id to the `"Request"` object you would either pass it in the *request* url or in the *request* body in the case of `PUT/PATCH/POST`.

So in your case you need to ensure that the #new action either posts to:

```
post "/managers/charges/:request_id"
```

Or that the form includes

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'request_id', @request.id %>
```

**PS**

`Request` although not technically a *reserved word* is a really bad name for a model since it will eventually cause conflicts and confusion with `ActionDispatch::Request` especially if you use the controller instance variable `@request`.

As you can see from the my answer above it gets confusing as h*ll since the word *request* is allready has a very specific connotation in web development.

The same applies to `Response`.

Use `PaymentRequest` or [any other synonym](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/request?s=t).

Comment: Request is not the actual name i just changed it to make it easier to understand. But wont the hidden tag send it to a model and not the controller action? There is no charge model

Comment: No. Rails does not automatically assign params to models.

Comment: So then what would the syntax look like when I am calling it in the controller. Since it doesn't use params

Comment: Dude what are you talking about? Of course it uses params. The "syntax" is `params[:request_id]`. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters

Comment: Rails will not automatically take that param however and pass it to a model in your controller.

Comment: I added the hidden_field_tag view but I get the error...````Problem: Document(s) not found for class Request with id(s) {:value=>BSON::ObjectId('562e3cef726169719c000002')}. ```` I edited the question adding the new view.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a form in the `charges/new`view, you can set the `request_id` using a hidden form field:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :request_id, @request.id %>
```

You should add the line above between `<%= form_for ... do |f| %>` and `<% end %>`.

In that example, you were assuming the `create` action would somehow have a `request_id` passed in automatically. Rails doesn't do that, in every request you need to explicitly provide all the information for the controller to process that request.

I hope that helps! ;)